# Dealing with datasources in grails in connection with BootStrap.groovy

Tags: mysql, grails, installation, bootstrapping

I'm currently developing a new project in Grails and right now all the information concerning datasources is within `DataSource.groovy`. I have also got some code in `BootStrap.groovy` in order to initialize the database in case of the first start in order to fill some tables with constant values.

Now I'm wondering how I could realize some kind of an "installer". I'm thinking of a customer who uses the `.war` of my software and needs to configure the database parameters (URL, user, password) before the first start.

I was thinking about setting up a dummy database and later let him change the URL, user and password via a webpage as part of my software. But what will then happen with my `BootStrap`-code in order to initialize the new database? Or is there a possibility of let the user set the necessary parameters before the `BootStrap`-code is executed and create the new database as well? Would that be possible to realize within grails or would I have to place some `php`-code up front?

I'm thinking of using `grails`, `mysql` in connection with `database-migration plugin`.

I would be grateful for any advice on this behalf. Thank you in advance!

If something is unclear, please tell me so.

Comment: Sounds like the perfect use case for external configuration files. Check the Grails documentation for more information.

Comment: Does that mean to put the content of e.g. the `DataSource.groovy` into an externalized config file?

Comment: Among any other settings you want your customers to configure when they deploy your application, yes.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes everything a lot easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you consider using an external configuration file that will allow your customers to not only configure the data source(s) but any other aspects of your application when they deploy it.

The Grails [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) has detailed information about how this is accomplished.